# In Haskell does Integral typeclass imply Show typeclass?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I was trying to compile this code.

```
symmetric [] = True
symmetric [_] = True
symmetric l
    | (head l) == (last l) = symmetric (tail (init l))
    | otherwise = False

isPalindrome :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPalindrome n = symmetric (show n)
```

That code did not compile and I got a not very long 
  error message saying that it cannot deduce (Show a).

```
Could not deduce (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’
from the context (Integral a)
  bound by the type signature for
             isPalindrome :: Integral a => a -> Bool
  at 4.hs:7:17-39
Possible fix:
  add (Show a) to the context of
    the type signature for isPalindrome :: Integral a => a -> Bool
In the first argument of ‘symmetric’, namely ‘(show n)’
In the expression: symmetric (show n)
In an equation for ‘isPalindrome’:
    isPalindrome n = symmetric (show n)
```

It worked after changing this line

```
isPalindrome :: Integral a => a -> Bool
```

to

```
isPalindrome :: (Show a, Integral a) => a -> Bool
```

So I was thinking since every type in Integral is in Show,a Haskell compiler should be able to deduce (Show a) from (Integral a).

Comment: Integral doesn't necessarily imply show membership. I could create my own integral type and not implement show.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So I was thinking since every type in Integral is in Show

But not every type in `Integral` is in `Show`. That used to be the case in Haskell98, due to

```
class Show n => Num n
```

But that superclass relation prevents an awful lot of useful number types (“infinite-precision numbers”, global results of continuous functions, etc.). In modern Haskell, the classes `Show` and `Integral` have no relation at all, hence the compiler can't infer one from the other.

It is, however, indeed possible to show any *integral* number type independently of the actual `Show` class; use the [`showInt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showInt) function for this.

```
import Numeric (showInt)
isPalindrome :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPalindrome n = symmetric $ showInt n []
```